# Are there any FOSS libraries that are the result of ripping bits out of Android for plain Java?

Tags: java, android

Before you jump, yes i have heard of the recent project to make Android proper run on a plain JRE. This question is not about Android the platform but rather about leveraging the great stuff thats in there, and may be useful in parts, eg the bitmap/graphics stuff.

*PS* Yes lets ignore the obvious bits that dont make sense such as telephony etc.

Answer (score 0):

I know of at least one, a vcard processing library, [android-vcard](http://code.google.com/p/android-vcard/)